# How Spectre tolerates spam transactions?

Tags: blockchain, security, spam

**Spectre** is a DAG based (directed acyclic graph) distributed ledger (a structure as an alternative to blockchain based distributed ledger).

Is there any mechanism in **Spectre** to **prevent sending spam transactions**?

Comment: Why is preventing spam transactions a goal?

Comment: According to [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Spam_transactions): "Spam transactions are transactions which create undesirable extra load on the network due to not following Bitcoin best practices ...".

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a desire to avoid unnecessary load. But it is futile apart from cautioning people to avoid hurting the system during its growth phase.

In a system without identities there is no way to apply quota or ratelimiting per participant, and global ratelimiting only results in a denial-of-service attack. In practice the only thing that prevents spam is a free market; if people want to pay more for something than others, it will get in. This is independent of the type of consensus algorithm used to construct the chain.

Comment: I think the consensus is aimed at achieving a global agreement on a single single state of the network and is related to **transaction confirmation** not **sending transaction**. So, consensus cannot prevent **sending spam transactions**. For an **unidentified** network, one of the approaches to make it costly is **transaction fee** as it's done in Bitcoin or Ethereum. But how about Spectre?

Comment: Spectre has nothing to do with it. It's a replacement for deciding what the best valid chain is. It's unrelated to the economics of what people may want to put in the chain.

Comment: So, do you mean is not possible to use Spectre as a cryptocurrency? when you say: _"It's unrelated to the economics of what people may want to put in the chain"_

Comment: No, I mean that Spectre doesn't change anything. Start with a cryptocurrency with the most-work rule, replace that rule with Spectre... now everything related to spam transactions still holds.